# SQLIite update all ids in table +24000

Tags: sqlite

I have a table in SQLite database with id, name, date_time, starting fom id=1 to id=1600.
I would like to change id to start from 24000, 24001 ...

Comment: `UPDATE yourTable SET id = id + 23999` ?

Comment: Thank you, I should have find this. It woorks!

Answer (score 0):

You can update SQLite table as Tim suggested. Update should run only one time.

```
UPDATE tablename SET id = id + 23999;
```

[SQLite update query tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_update_query.htm)